# Is there a way to find out if the STDOUT is being redirected, and if so which file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have an application which has the ability to run Ruby scripts in process. In ruby there is a way to evaluate `cmd.exe` commands and then returns the stdout. For example:

```
a=`echo "hello world"` #=> a = "hello world"
```

However the above example only works on a system where the user has admin privileges. I'm trying to debug why this may be...

One potential reason could be that the ruby engine is redirecting the `stdout` to a file which I do not have permission to write to. I can do the following:

```
echo "Hello World" > "some\file.txt"
```

... and this works, so the commands are at least executing.

So this brings me to my question. Is there a command in `cmd.exe` which I can use to see if the stdout is being redirected or even better to get the file which stdout is being redirected to?

Comment: just modify ruby and tell it where stdout should go.

Comment: The answer is yes, but you should ask this question at [SuperUser](https://SuperUser.com).  There's more than one way to get your goal, but they all pretty much involve listing the running processes and filtering the output to find your running script, which would obviously be a child of a ruby instance.  You can set your window title to a unique identifier and then find the process with that window title, then lookup the command line for the process and see all the gory details.

Comment: @jwdonahue oh wow... You can see all that via pid? Well knowing that information I should be able to work it out from there! Cheers :)